# Converting datetime.time to int for use in regression model / initial scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I am looking to change a datetime.time column in a pandas dataframe to an int value that isnt a unix like time i.e. from 1970 epoch.

Example of df.head(3):

| trans_date_trans_time | amt | category | city_pop | is_fraud | Time of Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:18 | 4.97 | misc_net | 3495 | 0 | 00:00:18 |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:44 | 107.23 | grocery_pos | 149 | 0 | 00:00:44 |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:51 | 220.11 | entertainment | 4154 | 0 | 00:00:51 |

So i want the 'Time of Day' column to read like an integer that can run along an axis of a simple scatter plot against 'amt'.

When I try:

```
y = int(df_full_slim['Time of Day'])

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

or simply:

```
y = df_full_slim['Time of Day']

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

it doesnt work as it cant plot a datetime.time type on a plt.

How do I get the time in a format that will run along an axis of a plot?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You can plot without conversion by calling the .plot() method of the dataframe:

```
df_full_slim.plot(x='Time of Day', y='amt')
```

Comment: If I am looking to eventually run a regression model on this to determine the relationship between the two variables or even to create a scatter plot instead of the plot given by the method you have outlines I need it to be in int format - appreciate the help though

Comment: This means you need to do some sort fo conversion. You could do a conversion to total secods, for instance: `df['Time of Day'].dt.second`.

Comment: This would only give the seconds from the time i.e. 1 through 59 and count all occurrences of that second regardless of hour and minute - i need the scale to remain at the full 24 hours in the day

Comment: convert it to total seconds?  `3600*df['Time of Day'].dt.hour + 60*df['Time of Day'].dt.minute + df['Time of Day'].dt.second`